# Single and double taps on UITableViewCell in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have storyboard segue on TableViewCell, which I use for transfering to another VC on cell click in `didSelectRowAt` method. Now I made double tap `TapGestureRecognizer` to handle touble tap on cell. Problem is that on single tap, segue is performing and double tap is not working. Double tap works fine with clicking out of cell. Is possible to solve this somehow with my code so far? Or I need to delete segue and handle single tap and double tap separately. 
Thanks for any suggestions

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap))
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
}

func handleDoubleTap(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let p = recognizer.location(in: tableView)

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: p)

    if let _ = indexPath {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath!, animated: true)
        update(index: (indexPath?.row)!, isFinished: true)
    }

    print ("doubke")
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showSingleTask") {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let destinationVC = nav.topViewController as! ShowTaskVC
            destinationVC.singleTask = tasks[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    self.selectedTask = tasks[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: So I have a question.. Do you want to double tap on the cell in order for it to call the segue ? Perhaps giving a bit more details would help.

Comment: Disable default tap of cell and add a single tap gesture on cell just like you added the double tap.

Comment: @JArango I want double tap on cell to call handleDoubleTap method and single tap on cell to perform segue and I want to know if it's possible to do it with didSelectRowAt method or I need to add single tap gesture as suggested above

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Solution

```
protocol MultiTappableDelegate: class {
    func singleTapDetected(in view: MultiTappable)
    func doubleTapDetected(in view: MultiTappable)
}

class ThreadSafeValue<T> {
    private var _value: T
    private lazy var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    init(value: T) { _value = value }
    var value: T {
        get {
            semaphore.signal(); defer { semaphore.wait() }
            return _value
        }
        set(value) {
            semaphore.signal(); defer { semaphore.wait() }
            _value = value
        }
    }
}

protocol MultiTappable: UIView {
    var multiTapDelegate: MultiTappableDelegate? { get set }
    var tapCounter: ThreadSafeValue<Int> { get set }
}

extension MultiTappable {
    func initMultiTap() {
        if let delegate = self as? MultiTappableDelegate { multiTapDelegate = delegate }
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIView.multitapActionHandler))
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func multitapAction() {
        if tapCounter.value == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
                usleep(250_000)
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    if self.tapCounter.value > 1 {
                        self.multiTapDelegate?.doubleTapDetected(in: self)
                    } else {
                        self.multiTapDelegate?.singleTapDetected(in: self)
                    }
                    self.tapCounter.value = 0
                }
            }
        }
        tapCounter.value += 1
    }
}

private extension UIView {
    @objc func multitapActionHandler() {
        if let tappable = self as? MultiTappable { tappable.multitapAction() }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
class MyView: UIView, MultiTappable {
    weak var multiTapDelegate: MultiTappableDelegate?
    lazy var tapCounter = ThreadSafeValue(value: 0)
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        initMultiTap()
    }
}
```

### Full sample

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 10 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.label.text = "\(indexPath)"
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: TableViewCellDelegate {
    func singleTapDetected(in cell: TableViewCell)  {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) { print("singleTap \(indexPath) ") }
    }
    func doubleTapDetected(in cell: TableViewCell) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) { print("doubleTap \(indexPath) ") }
    }
}
```

> TableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol TableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func singleTapDetected(in cell: TableViewCell)
    func doubleTapDetected(in cell: TableViewCell)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, MultiTappable {
    weak var multiTapDelegate: MultiTappableDelegate?
    lazy var tapCounter = ThreadSafeValue(value: 0)

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    weak var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        initMultiTap()
    }
}

extension TableViewCell: MultiTappableDelegate {
    func singleTapDetected(in view: MultiTappable) { self.delegate?.singleTapDetected(in: self) }
    func doubleTapDetected(in view: MultiTappable) { self.delegate?.doubleTapDetected(in: self) }
}
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="12118" systemVersion="16E195" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="g2V-T0-sqD">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="12086"/>
        <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_43153530" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fQm-mQ-a9u">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <prototypes>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="TableViewCell" id="nsF-ue-0bK" customClass="TableViewCell" customModule="stackoverflow_43153530" customModuleProvider="target">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="44"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="nsF-ue-0bK" id="pT6-2N-oTC">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="44"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fEK-J3-oqH">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="42" height="21"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="fEK-J3-oqH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="pT6-2N-oTC" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="Vfg-Ij-f6c"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="fEK-J3-oqH" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="pT6-2N-oTC" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="tc0-qJ-N1n"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                        <connections>
                                            <outlet property="label" destination="fEK-J3-oqH" id="YBJ-tG-J5T"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </prototypes>
                            </tableView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="fQm-mQ-a9u" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="wfy-db-euE" secondAttribute="top" id="8Vy-l8-jpB"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="fQm-mQ-a9u" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="Wwr-ox-Qbd"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="fQm-mQ-a9u" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-64" id="xJR-Uk-rbj"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="fQm-mQ-a9u" secondAttribute="trailing" id="zxs-ED-Whb"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="pLJ-Bz-NIm"/>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="tableView" destination="fQm-mQ-a9u" id="DhZ-jj-zmB"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1079.2" y="137.18140929535232"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="w7e-Wj-oUR">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="g2V-T0-sqD" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="7qG-8v-S0O">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="yqZ-pK-Yf3"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="tnz-x0-vDN" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="140" y="137.18140929535232"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works! even though it seems have delay to change some UI

Comment: @Vasily Bodnarchuk will it also work in the same way for UICollectionView?

Comment: @MD.SazidHasanDip yes. You can use the same Idea for UICollectionView.

Answer (score 2):

In cell class add follow methods:

```
private func addSingleAndDoubleTapGesture() {
    let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSingleTap))
    singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)

    let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap))
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    self.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

    singleTapGesture.require(toFail: doubleTapGesture)
}

@objc private func handleSingleTap(_ tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

}

@objc private func handleDoubleTap(_ tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was enough to add a double-tap gesture recognizer inside the **UITableViewCell** class.
Like this.

```
class TableViewCellSubclass: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    
        let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapFunc))
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        self.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
    }

    @objc func doubleTapFunc() {
    }
}
```

And for a single tap just use the **didSelectRowAt** method as usual.

Comment: I agree. It works rather cleanly.  The double-tap gesture is handled completely independently of the single-tap that takes you into ```didSelectRowAt``` so there is no worry about one stepping over the other and messing up the tap counts. Using your example above, I added ```protocol TableViewCellSubclassDelegate { func doubleTapped(cell: TableViewCellSubclass) }``` and then ```@objc func doubleTapFunc() { delegate?.doubleTapped(cell: self) }```. The viewcontroller which implements this protocol will then be able to catch this double tap and do whatever it wants with it.