# How to recognize which cell was tapped once and which was tapped twice

Tags: swift, uitableview

there! I would like to get to know which cell is tapped once and which is tapped twice. I have two classes, one for TableViewController and the other one for TableViewCell. I would like to manipulate cells regarding the touch but I cannot get their indexPath.

TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

var elements: [[Int16]] = Array(repeating:Array(repeating:0, count:2), count:10)

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return elements.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if(elements[indexPath.row][1] == 1) //if red
    {
        cell.Label.text = String(elements[indexPath.row][0] * 3)
        cell.Circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    else //if blue
    {
        cell.Label.text = String(elements[indexPath.row][0])
        cell.Circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height/10
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    for i in 0..<elements.count
    {
        elements[i][0] = Int16(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
        elements[i][1] = Int16(Int(arc4random_uniform(2)))
    }

    Memory().save(entity: elements)
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell

{

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()

    Circle.layer.cornerRadius = Circle.frame.width / 2

    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedOnce))
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedTwice))
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)

    singleTap.require(toFail: doubleTap)
    singleTap.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    doubleTap.delaysTouchesBegan = true
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

@objc func tappedOnce(sender: AnyObject?)
{
        print("1111111")
        //Memory().reload(reload: x, I: x)
}

@objc func tappedTwice()
{
    print("2222222")
}

@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Circle: UIView!

}
```

Inside the cells I have a label storing a random number (label) from 0 to 10 next to which there is a circle - blue or red (they are also random at start). If the circle is red, then the number (label) shows the number multiplied by three. All this is there.

Now... I want to change the number by touching on the cell once and make it 0 by touching on it twice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single and double taps on UITableViewCell in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153530/single-and-double-taps-on-uitableviewcell-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

> TableViewController:

```
var elements: [[Int16]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating:0, count:2), count:10)

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //MARK: - UIViewController LifeCycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        for i in 0..<elements.count {
            elements[i][0] = Int16(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
            elements[i][1] = Int16(Int(arc4random_uniform(2)))
        }
        Memory().save(entity: elements)
    }


    //MARK: - UITableView Delegate & DataSource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return elements.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        if elements[indexPath.row][1] == 1 {
            cell.Label.text = String(elements[indexPath.row][0] * 3)
            cell.Circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else {
            cell.Label.text = String(elements[indexPath.row][0])
            cell.Circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height/10
    }
}
```

> TableViewCell:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Circle: UIView!
    private var tapCounter = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        Circle.layer.cornerRadius = Circle.frame.width / 2

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    @objc func tapAction() {

        if tapCounter == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                usleep(250000)
                if self.tapCounter > 1 {
                    self.tappedTwice()
                }
                else {
                    self.tappedOnce()
                }
                self.tapCounter = 0
            }
        }
        tapCounter += 1
    }

    func tappedOnce() {
        print("1111111")
    }
    func tappedTwice() {
        print("2222222")
    }
}
```

Take reference from here
[Single and double taps on UITableViewCell in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153530/single-and-double-taps-on-uitableviewcell-in-swift-3)

Comment: ok, it's better but how can I now get the indexPath for the tapped cell?

Comment: you can use delegate protocol to get indexpath